# Virtualbox Kernel driver error: Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox

I have a fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04. When I started my virtual machine, it said kernel driver not installed.
[image]

Tried running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`. Not solved.

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

(last time when I had this error, I reinstalled Ubuntu and the problem was gone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the `build-essential` packages installed to build the kernel modules. You can resolve this issue with just a couple of commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Then you can try your `vboxconfig` command again.